# How to right circular shift a number without using any data structures?

Tags: c++, algorithm

suppose we are given input number as 1234 then after right circular shift we should get 4123 as output.
I tried solving it using MOD operator but it didnt work.

Comment: No code, no actual output - how do you expect us to find the bug in your code?

Comment: Perhaps your question should show what you tried, what you expected to happen, what actually happened, and finally ask a question about what you don't understand about the difference between what happened and what you expected.

Comment: The suggested duplicate appears to be about binary shift, while this question appears to be about shifting in base 10, so I don't think the answers in the duplicate are of much use and I don't think it's an appropriate duplicate. That said, I voted to close this question as off topic because of lack of mcve and I'm not voting to reopen until the question has been improved.

Comment: The question should be closed, but not as a dupe - it is different from the linked answer. Let's keep it consistent. @user2079303, it's open now, so you can join me and vote to close it with a proper reason.

Comment: @SergeyA I can't vote because "[I] voted to close this question 22 mins ago"

Comment: What's wrong with data structures?

Comment: There is no MOD operator. Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Your task can solved this way:

```
unsigned int CSWR(unsigned int i) {
    unsigned int rem = i % 10;
    unsigned int temp = i / 10;
    i = temp;
    if (!i)
        return rem;

    for(rem *=10;i/=10;rem *= 10);
    return rem + temp;
}
```

Comment: it worked @Anatoly

Answer (score 1):

Or, this way:

```
int a = 1234;
int result = (a/10) + (a%10)*pow(10,(int)log10(a));
```